# Custom Android Studio Library Class Error: Cannot find symbol class

Tags: android, android-studio, shared-libraries

I created custom library as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298658/android-library-project-using-android-studio). I also created new activity in library and I extend it in activity of main application. This is working, but activity must be written in manifest of library, otherwise it is not working.

Now I want to use simple class from library, but it is not working. I can call this class from activity of main application, but when I try to run application, it shows error: Error:(19, 41) error: cannot find symbol class Font

```
public class Font{

public static void SetFontBoldTextView(Context context,TextView textView)
{
    Typeface typefaceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontBold);
    textView.setTypeface(typefaceBold);
}
```

}

Rebuild and clean didn´t help.
Please advice what I do wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I found source of problem, it was "minifyEnabled true". After I disable proguard, it is working.